# MacOS High Sierra Drush only gives 2 options

Tags: php, composer-php, drush, macos-high-sierra

So today I was installing Drush via Composer. it was completely installed according to terminal but in /usr/local/bin there is no Drush folder.

I tried before and then I tried with Composer as well, but since that failed I tried via Homebrew but since I work with MAMP, it only gave 2 options (cancel and drush) and yea then I uninstalled that and tried again with composer even did a fresh install.

I did the "composer global show -P" command and It's in /users/mymacname/.composer then it outputs a giant list like: 
composer-plugin-api 1.1.0 The Composer Plugin API

so when I go to that location, there is a .composer folder, 
when I go in that folder - vendor - bin - there are:

- drush
- drush.complete.sh
- drush.launcher
- drush.php
- php-parse
- psysh

thats all there is and when I type drush, or drush status it gives "-bash: drush: command not found

How can I solve this?

Greetings Ditger

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the step where you have to add the export to your .bash_profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/[username]/drush
```

this is of course specific to my install, you will have to find where your drush is installed and appropriately add the export path